# Regex to ignore something

Tags: regex

I'm trying to clean up a file with a bunch of useless data.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSE8X.png)

It's matching the part outlined in red but I need it not to because that part has a group: specified. Not sure how to ignore sections that have a group.

The expression I have `.*:\n.*options:\n.*name:.*`

Example of what it matches:

```
  06c73c64-ba81-4e22-8b4b-4ccb46fe6f32:
    options:
      name: Crusty_Sword
```

Example of what it shouldn't match:

```
  06c73c64-ba81-4e22-8b4b-4ccb46fe6f32:
    options:
      name: Crusty_Sword
    group:
    - Elite
```

Comment: Please post the raw data instead of images,

Comment: @CodeManiac my bad. Updated it.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a lookahead to assert that the next line is empty:

```
.*:\n.*options:\n.*name:.*(?=\n$)
```

Demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/eowega/1).

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. `(.*:\n.*options:\n.*name:.*\n)(?!\s+group)`